# applicability in or to

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I have the following sentence:

"Method A has drawbacks that limit its applicability **in** real-world environments"

Can I use 'in' here or do I have to use 'to'? I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Depends on context/tone.

Comment: I agree: *applicability **in** real-world environments* and *applicability **to** real-world environments* have different meanings.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Hot Licks and Greybeard. What I want to say is that the specific Method A which has been applied in simulations, has drawbacks (especially regarding runtimes) that might make it difficult/costly to apply it in reality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Apply* and *applicable* take a complement (an essential part of their meaning) with "to".

If you say *applicable to real-world environments*, you are stating that the real-world environments are (among) the things that it applies to.

"In" does not introduce a complement of *apply* or *applicable*, so it must be an adjunct with its normal meaning. So *applicable in real-world environments* must be talking about the environment within which it applies, not the things that it applies to (which are understood).

Whether there is a substantive difference in meaning depends on factors outside the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Colin Fine.  I do not fully understand your answer to be totally honest. What I want to say is that the specific Method A which has been applied in simulations, has drawbacks (especially regarding runtimes) that might make it difficult/costly to apply it in reality.

Comment: What is the method being applied to? Is it being applied to the real-world environment, or is it being applied to something else **in** the real-world environment? I suspect the latter.

Comment: Thanks Colin Fine for your answer. To be totally honest, I do not understand the difference between being applied to 'real-world environment, or is it being applied to something else in the real-world environmet'. The method can't be applied (according to my analysis) in/to real-world environment. Only in simulations of a residential area it can be applied.

Comment: I have no idea about the real-world limitations of what this might mean. The question I am asking is whether it makes sense to talk about the method being applied to an environment, or whether the method is applied to something else (which happens to take place in an environment). Since I have no idea what the method is, or does, or applies to, I cannot answer this question, as you evidently can.

Comment: Thanks Colin Fine for your answer. So this optimization method basically jointly controls the heating devices in buildings in residential areas. In simulations this can be done but in reality I state that it can not be applied due to privacy and complexity (of the algorithms used) reasons. So basically the Method is applied in/to residential area. To come back to my inital question: Do I have to use 'in' or 'to'?

Comment: @PeterBe: So, if I understand your answer, the method applies to control of heating devices, not to environments (in the sense of real/simulation).

Comment: Thanks Colin Fine for your comment. Yes your are right. And what I want to say is that, opposed to simulations, the application of the method in reality might be difficult.

Comment: So does that answer your original question?

Comment: Do I have to use 'in real-world environments' or 'to real-world environments'?

Comment: No it does not answer my quesiton.

Comment: @PeterBe: you don't **have** to do anything. Both will be understood in context, and have similar meanings. But judging from your answers above, the method does not apply **to** the environment in any way - it applies to something else - so _in_ fits your meaning better.

Answer (score 0):

The comments give out that there is a difference, and I believe there is at least an essential one, which is this. When you use "in" the whole environment isn't targeted, but instead some element immersed in it is or  an element *of* the environment is, whereas the use of "to" implies the understanding that the whole environment is meant ([OALD, in 1](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/in_1?q=in), [OALD, to 8](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/to_1?q=to)).

If the method is applied to something *in* the environment and not *to* the environment itself, as this seems to be the case, then "in" should be used.

Comment: Just so. In this case, **in = inside or within**.