# Contrast is followed by in

Tags: prepositions

Could please anyone explain why *contrast* is followed by *in*, not *with* or *to* in this sentence from Cambridge Dictionary?

> We use *actually* to indicate a new topic of conversation or a change
> or contrast **in** what is being talked about.

Comment: They're all acceptable. But you can only choose one, as the writer has done.

Comment: I think "in" properly locates the subject of what is being discussed in the discourse (person's speech) itself. "In what we are saying, there is only truth". "in" is used for locations. So, the contrast is "in" what is being talked about. In other words, in "refers to what is being talked about". :) Hope that is clear.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to a question [recently asked](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/530828/349876); [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/530831/349876) is applicable here. The usual prepositions are "between", "with" and "to" and they introduce a noun complement. As "in" does not introduce a complement, it must be an adjunct. This adjunct, "in what is being talked about", tells where a contrast is found; it must be understood that it is found betwween the elements constituting what is being talked about.

---

*Answer to comment from [user anna299](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530906/contrast-is-followed-by-in/530913#comment1296140_530913)*

I made up two examples that are plausible but not to be taken, as concerns what they say from a sociological point of view, as accurate accounts of  real professional discussions. They show that the two prepositions correspond to two different contexts and that, incidentally, the phrase could have been "contrast in/to what is being talked about". In my opinion, the prepositions cannot be interchanged in either one of the two examples below.

1. The question of raising children is a matter that is difficult to consider in the context of working parents in the nuclear family. There are six cases to consider. Actually, the case of working parents who both work numerous overtime hours is not to be considered because it appears impossible to preserve much of a family life in such a work context.

"Actually" is used to  indicate a contradiction **in** what is being talked about, that is, the various types of contexts which are those concerning working parents.

2. The question of raising children is a matter that is difficult to consider in the context of working parents in the nuclear family. There are six cases to consider. Actually, the extended family does not usually give rise to the basic questions about raising children.

"Actually" is used to  indicate a contrast **to** what is being talked about, that is, the nuclear family.

Comment: Thanks for the  reply!
If the sentence were _contrast **to** what is being talked about_ would its meaning really change somehow, in your opinion? Maybe only formally?

Comment: @anna299 Apparently the notification of your comment was never properly made evident to me, so it is only now, after today's new activity that I see it. I'll make an addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the conjunction you get 3 sentences

> We use actually to indicate a new topic of conversation
>
> We use actually to indicate a change in what is being talked about
>
> We use actually to indicate a contrast in what is being talked about

"Contrast in" is used in identifying where the contrast is. For instance, "Contrast in appearance"

The other versions are generally used to actively compare different instances.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
Maybe you meant "Contrast in" is used in identifying the **object** of contrast? 
**Appearance** looks like an object in your example.
What do you mean by saying that it identifies criteria? Please give an example if possible.

Comment: I was using those terms colloquially, I have corrected my answer for clarity

Comment: "in" can identify the nature of the difference (as this answer describes), but it can also identify the category in which all the different things are found e.g. "a difference in the documents".

Answer (score 0):

I think it simply means that the part that follows ***actually*** in a sentence, will ***contain*** *a new topic of conversation or a change or contrast* compared to something that was asserted before ***actually***. For example:

> I was looking forward to reading your work on freedom of speech. ***Actually***, the majority of the essay regards the question of women's emancipation.

The clause "the majority of the essay regards the question of women's emancipation" is introduced by ***actually***, because there is a contrast ***IN*** it: between ***your work on freedom of speech*** and ***the majority of the essay regards the question of women's emancipation***.

"IN" merely expresses where something is:

> it expresses the situation of something that is or appears to be enclosed or surrounded by something else. ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02_4KuXmRNfjALznvTXMZ9axxX8aA%3A1610301286998&source=hp&ei=Zj_7X-SOOsKUa7rIgNgP&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAX_tNds8kYP80aUlSIuLg4ZaWlZc13N5Z&q=in%20meaning&oq=in%20meanin&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgUIABDJAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoECCMQJzoFCAAQkQI6CAgAELEDEIMBOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoFCAAQsQM6CQgjECcQRhD5AToKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoICAAQyQMQkQI6AgguOggILhCxAxCDAToFCC4QsQNQ4wZY3xFgghtoAHAAeACAAYsBiAHGB5IBAzUuNJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab))